# XSLT: do a comparison based on a list

Tags: xslt

I've got a list, with paired values:
aircon, aircon_no - these two values are a pair
ABS, ABS_no
heatedseats, heatedseats_no
etc.

So a pair is two values that start with the same substring. These values are stored in the @type attribute.
I've got about 50 pairs in my data.

I want to process an XML which looks like this:

```
<object type="aircon" id="1">
   ..
</object>
<object type="ABS" id="2">
   ..
</object>
<object type="heatedseats" id="3">
   ..
</object>
<object type="ABS" id="4">
   ..
</object>
<object type="ABS_no" id="5">
   ..
</object>
```

This is a short excerpt, the data contains hundreds of "object" nodes.

The operation depends on the type attribute of the "object" node, and the type attr. of the preceding "object" node. I could find those like this:

```
<if test="@type='ABS_no' and preceding-sibling::object/@type='ABS'"> ...
```

My list of paired values is quite long, so I get a long list of these `if` statements.

Is there a way to avoid creating a long list of `if` statements, and instead have a more general statement that works for each of my pairs:

```
<if test="@type='-second value of a pair-' and preceding-sibling::object[1]/@type='-first value of that same pair-'">
```

and get the whole list of pairs into a single statement?

The goal is to find node ABS_no if it is preceded by node ABS (so @id='5' in my example list), and do this for each pair of values.

The XSLT is passthrough, except for one template that matches the  nodes. If these pass the test, an extra subnode is added to the  node.

I use XSLT2, but XSLT3 is an option if it helps.

Comment: What **exactly** defines a "pair"? And what is the expected result?

Comment: I've added some info to the question.

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? How do you process the elements further up, in what kind of template is the `if` (`xsl:if`?) you have? And what kind of output do you want to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a pair is two values that start with the same letter.
> ...
> The goal is to find node B2 if it is preceded by node B1

I am not sure that constitutes a well-defined problem (what if there is a sequence B1, B2, B3?), but I believe this will do what you asked for:

```
<xsl:for-each select="object[position() > 1 and starts-with(@type, substring(preceding-sibling::object[1]/@type, 1, 1))]">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

***--- added in responses to your edit ---***

> the _ is the separator between the common substring of a pair and the unique part of the values

In such case you could select (or match):

```
object[substring-before(@type, '_') = preceding-sibling::object[1]/@type]
```

But if you can use XSLT 2.0, grouping might be a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks. I see I've oversimplified, I'll improve the example.

Comment: I can rule out "pairs" with more than 2 values. Looking at the data, the _ is the separator between the common substring of a pair and the unique part of the values. So I could modify your code with something using substring-after...

Comment: I believe it would be `substring-before()` - see the addition to my post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<xsl:for-each-group select="object" group-by="replace(@type, '_.*$', '')"` and then each pair would be a group.

Comment: interesting approach, looks like I have some studying to do (haven't used groups yet).

Comment: It seems to me this will create a group of all object nodes that share their group-by selector. So if i group by "ABS" I get ids 2, 4 and 5. My intent was to treat them as a group only if the elements are adjacent in the XML, so 4 and 5 should become a group, without 2. Sorry, I should have made that clearer in the description.

Comment: In that case, try `group-adjacent` instead of `group-by`.